# Can I trust Git Credential Manager by GitCredentialManager?

Tags: github, credentials, phishing

I've used Github desktop for a couple of years. Today it will suddenly would not log in to my account, although I have not changed password lately. When I click login with browser I'm taken to a page that says "Git Credential Manager by GitCredentialManager wants to access your account" and that I should authorize full read and write access.

Googling this has not given me any clues to why this would suddenly happen. Do I have to start using this service to login to Github desktop or could this be a phishing attempt?

Answer (score 1):

I was in the same boat. After Googling a bit, I found this post on the GitHub blog:
https://github.blog/2022-04-07-git-credential-manager-authentication-for-everyone/

Seems this is an official replacement for handling credentials in GitHub and Git Desktop.

Comment: Saw that to, but no information from Github desktop about the change yet - nor is it mentioned in the sign in documentation so find that quite strange. Perhaps a small canary deployment to some users